# Visual Studio 2010 crashes on right click

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, right-click, visual-studio-2015

I had this problem in Windows 7, and now with a post-formatted and very clean C:\ disk with Windows 8.1 x64, I have it too.

When I am executing a Visual C++ application from within Visual Studio 2010 and I right-click to show the right-menu (for example to "Watch value" of a variable), Visual Studio comes unresponsive.

To make VS become responsive, I have to go to Task manager to Stop the application in question.

And the consequence of this and after I loose the flux of my debug session, because Stepping more through the flux causes the application to Stop.

I repeat that my Windows 8 installation is almost clean because the disk was formatted, and Visual Studio 2010 installation is almost clean having only Service Pack 1, but no extensions.

Please help.

**UPDATE 1:**

I think the crash happens only or happens more frequently on a delimited situation; the Debugger is paused and :

- I right-click on a variable name

OR

- after doing a Find in Files I Double-Click on a result line of the Find Results Window of a not yet open file

This makes me believe it has something to do with refreshing Intellisense.

**UPDATE 2:**

In reply to recent comments, I've been searching where VS 2010 put its own dump files and I could not find them. On the other hand I got this info from Windows Event Viewer:

[image: VS 2010 event Log Viewer]

and the Details tab contains this text:

- System

  - Provider

  [ Name]  Application Hang

  - EventID 1002

  [ Qualifiers]  0

  Level 2

  Task 101

  Keywords 0x80000000000000

  - TimeCreated

  [ SystemTime]  2014-01-14T17:20:03.000000000Z

  EventRecordID 2266

  Channel Application

  Computer

  Security
- EventData

  devenv.exe 
  10.0.40219.1 
  a50 
  01cf110ab9e8178b 
  428 
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe 
  0736177c-7d40-11e3-be6c-002258cc989b

  55006E006B006E006F0077006E0000000000

---

Binary data:

In Words

0000: 006E0055 006E006B 0077006F 0000006E 
0010: 0000

In Bytes

0000: 55 00 6E 00 6B 00 6E 00   U.n.k.n.
0008: 6F 00 77 00 6E 00 00 00   o.w.n...
0010: 00 00                     ..

**UPDATE 3:**

I've just repeatedly noticed that this issue only happens on projects with some complexity, not happening on very simple ones. 
Now, due to some evidence on projects that have dependency on outside libraries, I suspect the bug happens when the debugger is trying to get the data for the "Resolve Ambiguity" dialog. 
[image: Resolve Ambiguity dialog]

One way to increase the likeliness of making happen the undesired behavior is to Right-click and do "Set Next Statement".

**UPDATE 4:**

Bug still present on Visual Studio 2015 Preview.

Comment: Can you take a dump of Visual Studio when it crashes and post it somewhere?  Given the context of the crash I don't think anyone will be able to explain it without examining a crash dump

Comment: It's not clear what kind of 'help' you're looking for - if Visual Studio is crashing, we're not likely to be able to make it "not" crash. It's likely you'll get more useful help from MS directly...

Comment: The first thing to do is to disable your add-ons and extensions. The second thing to do is to reset your settings (start devenv.exe with the /ResetSettings flag).