# Visual C++ hangs and I can not kill application

Tags: visual-c++, freeze, kill-process

The behavior I describe I already knew it since VS2008, and I've seen it on every update we made to it (VS2010, VS2013).

When running my application, Visual C++ hangs becoming unresponsive. Then I go to Task Manager to kill its process. Some times happens 1, sometimes happens 2.

1. Visual Studio responds again. However, the application process becomes immortal, I try to kill it in Task Manager and it says "Access denied". Then, I try to open Task Manager again, but this time having an Administrative user and I still see "Access denied." I have to Restart Visual Studio, to get rid of the Zombie application's process.
2. Visual Studio his hanging forever. I don't know any option better than killing VS. This is worse, because I loose my whole debugging session.

Questions:

- For 1. given I can not kill the app process outside Visual Studio (I presume the reason is because the process is Child of the VS process), is there anyway to kill it from Visual Studio? Or any extension that allows to do it?
- For 2. is there any better option than killing VS?
- Is there any known progress on this issue for VS2015?

Comment: Clearly your machine is infected with a virus.  Most common is the kind that programmers voluntarily install.  If it is the truly aggressive crapware like Avast then get rid of it completely, it is unfit to run on a programmer's machine.

Comment: @HansPassant: I had several machines, several formattings and reinstallations  and this behavior was present in every of them. What scares me on your comment is "Clearly". How can you be so sure?

Comment: I have observed similar VS symptoms in situations where a networked project location was involved. Do you by any chance have the solution or project located on a remote share or use a UNC path for some included files?

Comment: @TonPlooij: No. But it may be relevant the application integrates a DLL that does some networking communications to an HPGL-commanded cutting machine; and it is also multi-threaded, has critical sections, has some omp parallelism and includes also libraries that do omp paralleslism.

Comment: I am now suspecting this is caused by a background thread that is periodically executing a `Sleep(50)` on itself. And I also suspect that another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21097048/visual-studio-2010-crashes-on-right-click asked by me is somewhat related. The strange thing is when I do Freeze of this Thread on the Threads Window of Visual Studio, the Thread continues running!